# MySQL not a valid win32 application

Tags: mysql, executable

I'm running mysqldump.exe with needed parameters from cmd and this all works fine.

Then, all of the sudden, it started to give me a popup "Not a valid win32 application" and in the console it's saying 'Access is denied...'

What's causing this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: sounds like the executable became corrupted.

Comment: Jeremy has a good comment. try downloading the .exe again. ALso, If the program is designed for a 64-bit version of Windows and you're running it in a 32-bit version of Windows, it will not work and generate this error. Hope this helps

Comment: executable became 0kb ... i copied new file, thanks guys!

Comment: @eddyuk where did you copy the new file?

Comment: @M.OğuzÖzcan In MySQL installation folder (in today versions C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\bin). I had it installed on another computer and took the file from there because I didn't want to reinstall.

Answer (score 1):

**CAUSE**
This issue may occur if the path of the executable file for the service 
contains spaces.

When Windows starts a service, it parses the path of the service from left to right. If both of the following conditions are true:

- The path of a service’s executable file contains spaces.
- There is a file or folder on your computer’s hard disk that has the same name as a file or folder in the path to the service's executable file.

Windows may locate and try to run the file or folder before it locates 
and runs the executable file for the service.

For example, if the path of the executable file for a service is 
`C:\Program Files\MyProgram\MyService.exe`, and if a folder that is named 
`C:\Program` also exists on your hard disk, Windows locates the `C:\Program` 
folder on your hard disk before the

```
C:\Program Files\MyProgram\My 
Service.exe
```

file, and then tries to run it.
**RESOLUTION**
WARNING: If you use Registry Editor incorrectly, you may cause serious problems that may require you to reinstall your operating system. 
Microsoft cannot guarantee that you can solve problems that result from using Registry Editor incorrectly. Use Registry Editor at your own risk. 
To resolve this issue, add quotation marks around the following value in 
the Windows registry, where  is the name of the service:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\<ServiceName>\ImagePath
```

The ImagePath value contains the other serviceable file for the 
service. To add quotation marks around the ImagePath value for a service:

1. Click Start, and then click Run.
2. In the Open box, type regedit, and then click OK.
3. Locate, and then click the following registry entry, where 
   `<ServiceName>` is the name of the service:
   `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\<ServiceName>`.
   For example, if the service is named MyService, locate the
   `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\MyService key`.
4. In the right pane, double-click ImagePath.
5. In the Value data box, add quotation marks around the complete path of the executable file for the service.

For example, if the path of the MyService service is

```
 C:\Program 
Files\MyProgram\MyService.exe
```

, change the entry in the Value data box 
for the MyService service to the following

"`C:\Program Files\MyProgram\MyService.exe`"
6. Click OK, and then quit Registry Editor./

So, create a new folder and installed services. 
BAM! It worked. I have a `C:\Web Dev\` folder I was using for testing and 
the space between web and dev was the problem.